# Having trouble to open jupyter notebook in browser

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I run the command "jupyter notebook" on terminal, it shows the below message on terminal and opens the empty page in browser.

---

> Last login: Mon Jan 17 19:51:03 on ttys000 (base)
> saumenduroy@Saumendus-MacBook-Air ~ % jupyter notebook [I 2022-01-17
> 19:53:05.370 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from
> /Users/saumenduroy/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab
> [I 2022-01-17 19:53:05.370 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is
> /Users/saumenduroy/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab [I 19:53:05.372
> NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory:
> /Users/saumenduroy [I 19:53:05.372 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0
> is running at: [I 19:53:05.372 NotebookApp]
> http://localhost:8888/?token=924366d4a3a260fb8f12fb4db709ccbc0f4b7a5417ec9874
> [I 19:53:05.372 NotebookApp]  or
> http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=924366d4a3a260fb8f12fb4db709ccbc0f4b7a5417ec9874 [I 19:53:05.372 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and
> shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation). [C 19:53:05.375
> NotebookApp]
>
> ```
> To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
>     file:///Users/saumenduroy/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1238-open.html
> Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
>     http://localhost:8888/?token=924366d4a3a260fb8f12fb4db709ccbc0f4b7a5417ec9874
>  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=924366d4a3a260fb8f12fb4db709ccbc0f4b7a5417ec9874 [E 19:53:06.609 NotebookApp] Could not open static file '' [W
> ```
>
> 19:53:06.651 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/tree/js/main.min.js (::1)
> 3.950000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree?token=924366d4a3a260fb8f12fb4db709ccbc0f4b7a5417ec9874

---

I am expecting your valuable answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @saumo.roy, what happens when you copy/paste the url (http://localhost:8888/?token=924366d4a3a260fb8f12fb4db709ccbc0f4b7a5417ec9874) into your browser url? (the token value may change at each launch)

Comment: It shows empty in browser when I copy and paste it.

Comment: What 'terminal' are you using to type the `jupyter notebook` command? Are you sure you are launching it locally?

Comment: I am launching terminal on my macbook.

Comment: What do you get when running the command `jupyter notebook list`, after having launched the first command?

Comment: Same thing occurs (nothing can load in browser)

Comment: I am not familiar with macs, but `jupyter notebook list` should show a (possibly empty) list of running notebooks. Are you sure you don't see anything like `Currently running servers:` when running this command (don't forget the `list` in the end!)

Comment: yeah, don't show anything in the browser

Comment: Actually, it should show up in the command line, not in the browser

Comment: Last login: Tue Jan 18 18:04:45 on ttys000
(base) saumenduroy@Saumendus-MacBook-Air ~ % jupyter notebook list
Currently running servers:
(base) saumenduroy@Saumendus-MacBook-Air ~ % jupyter notebook

Comment: If I understand what you posted, there seem to be no running jupyter notebook server. Did you type `jupyter notebook list` command right after `jupyter notebook` command, potentially on another terminal (you may not be able to type anything in the initial prompt). EDIT: do NOT interrupt the initial process